# How to create new columns based on values and names of existing columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with a number of columns such as `1_2014_precip` for January 2014 precipitation. This is a merge of two data sets. The first are agronomic variables, for example grain yield, which were collected in a given year. The second is weather data, which was downloaded for the entire period of time that any experiment was conducted. So I collected grain yield in one year, for example 2013, and I currently have columns for the weather that was experienced at that site in 2011-2019. I want to have a data set where I only have the data that corresponds to the year the yield was collected.

This data set spans all 12 months, 7 weather variables, and 10 years. I want to make columns such as `2_mean_temp`, corresponding to February mean temperature, and use the column `Year` to tell R where to look for the correct data (so if the entry in `Year` is 2019, the script would pull the value for the new column `2_mean_temp` from the existing column `2_2019_mean_temp`. I'm including an example of the data from two weather variables in two months in two years to give an idea of how I need this to be manipulated. I have figured out how to do this in Python, but for workflow purposes, I need to be able to do it in R. My main issue in R is I don't know how to tell R to go to a different column based on the value of a given column- I can't generate even the first column without automation.

```
    dput(head(df))
       structure(list(Experiment = c("IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", 
       "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate"), 
        Site = c("Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca"), 
        Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L),
        `1_2013_mean_temp` = c(-8.58677419354839, -8.58677419354839, -8.58677419354839, -8.58677419354839, -8.58677419354839, -8.58677419354839), 
        `1_2013_precip` = c(14.17, 14.17, 14.17, 14.17, 14.17, 14.17), 
        `1_2014_mean_temp` = c(-14.0787096774194, -14.0787096774194, -14.0787096774194, -14.0787096774194, -14.0787096774194, -14.0787096774194), 
        `1_2014_precip` = c(21.97, 21.97, 21.97, 21.97, 21.97, 21.97), 
        `2_2013_mean_temp` = c(-7.22428571428571, -7.22428571428571, -7.22428571428571, -7.22428571428571, -7.22428571428571, -7.22428571428571), 
        `2_2013_precip` = c(27.94, 27.94, 27.94, 27.94, 27.94, 27.94), 
        `2_2014_mean_temp` = c(-13.5003571428571, -13.5003571428571, -13.5003571428571, -13.5003571428571, -13.5003571428571, -13.5003571428571), 
        `2_2014_precip` = c(28.95, 28.95, 28.95, 28.95, 28.95, 28.95)), row.names = c(195L, 223L, 245L, 271L, 196L, 224L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I would like this sample of data to look like after it's been manipulated. Notice how there are no more years in the column names, and the data has been moved from the respective columns matching the appropriate year (2013_month_variable in the first four cases, 2014_month_variable in the last two cases).

```
df2 <- data.frame(Experiment = c("IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate", "IREE- N Rate"),
                  Site = c("Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca", "Waseca"),
                  Year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014),
                  1_mean_temp = c(-8.585774, -8.585774, -8.585774, -8.585774, -14.07871, -14.07871),
                  1_precip = c(14.17, 14.17, 14.17, 14.17, 21.97, 21.97),
                  2_mean_temp = c(-7.224286,-7.224286, -7.224286, -7.224286, -13.50036, -13.50036),
                  2_precip = c(27.94, 27.94, 27.94, 27.94, 28.95, 28.95))
```

Here's how I did it in Python.

```
    months = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
    variables = ['mean_temp', 'mean_max_temp', 'mean_min_temp', 'min_min_temp', 'mean_rh', 'precip', 'VPD']
    years = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
    
   for m in months:
           for var in variables:
               for year in years:
                    try:
                        df.loc[(df['Year'] == year), '_' + m + '_' + var] = df[m + '_' + year + '_' + var]
                    except:
                        print(year + '_' + m + '_' + var)
```

I can recreate the column names using a for loop in R, and after that is where I get stuck. I've tried doing it without automation, but I can't seem to find a way to get R to make which column R queries for a value based on the value of a different column.

```
years <- list("2013", "2014")
months <- list("1", "2")
vars <- list("mean_temp", "precip")
for (year in years) (
  for (month in months) (
    for (var in vars) {
      x = paste(year,"_", month,"_",var, sep="") 
    }
  )
)
```

Reshaping by year won't solve the problem, because it would create nonsensical columns like "2013_2011_1_mean_temp" and would not automate the connection of the weather data to the appropriate year in which the grain was collected.

Comment: What about `reshape(unique(df), idvar=c("Experiment", "Site"), timevar="Year", direction="wide")`?

Comment: Your expected output is not clear.

Comment: Why is there a `Year` column in the original dataset even though data from separate years are in different columns?

Comment: This is a merge of two data sets. The first are agronomic variables, for example grain yield, which were collected in a given year. The second is weather data, which was downloaded for the entire period of time that any experiment was conducted. So if I collected grain yield in 2013, I currently have columns for the weather that was experienced at that site in 2011-2019. I want to have a data set where I only have the data that corresponds to the year the yield was collected. I'll add this to the post for clarity.

Comment: I don't want the data reshaped- I want it to be in long form so that there is one entry for every grain yield observation. I just want to consolidate the weather data so that only the year in which the grain was collected remains. Using Python, I have generated what I call "relative columns," and then in R I have removed the original columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the result you're looking for; this solution uses tidyverse functions.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create empty tibble to store results
df.out <- tibble()

# loop over years
for (i in unique(df$Year)) {

  this.year <- df %>%
    # grab number of rows for this year
    filter(Year == i) %>%
    # only grab the weather columns for this specific year
    select(Experiment, Site, Year, contains(paste0("_", i, "_"))) %>%
    # this function uses a regex to rename columns with "_" and the current year by removing the part of the name with "_" then 4 numbers
    rename_with(function(x) {str_replace(x, "\\_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", "")}, contains(paste0("_", i, "_")))
  
  # add this year to your output tibble
  df.out <- df.out %>%
    bind_rows(this.year)
  
}
```

[image: final data frame]

Comment: This is a great start! When I run it on my data, the output has 9 times as many rows as the input (did it multiply by my 9 weather variables?). I notice your output has twice as many rows as the header I supplied as well. `dim(df)
[1] 5664 1054
> dim(df.out)
[1] 50976   111`

Comment: whoops! ok answer edited; just need to filter the data frame by the specific year to retain that number of rows before doing the manipulation. also removed the recreation of Year that i had, that's unnecessary.

Comment: This works great. For some reason the output has two fewer rows than the input. It's likely a problem with the data set, but the Python code didn't have that problem. I haven't been able to diagnose it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` and abusing `.SD` a bit makes for a concise solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
idvars <- c("Experiment", "Site", "Year") 
df2 <- df[, .SD[, .SD, .SDcols = names(.SD) %flike% last(.BY)], by = idvars]
setnames(df2, sub("\\d{4}_", "", names(df2)))


#      Experiment   Site Year 1_mean_temp 1_precip 2_mean_temp 2_precip
# 1: IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 2: IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 3: IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 4: IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 5: IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014  -14.078710    21.97  -13.500357    28.95
# 6: IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014  -14.078710    21.97  -13.500357    28.95
```

Using only base R:

```r
dfspl <- split(df, df$Year)
for (i in seq_along(dfspl)) {
  df2 <- dfspl[[i]][!(names(df) %in% idvars | grepl(names(dfspl)[i], names(df)))] <-
    NULL
  names(dfspl[[i]]) <- sub("\\d{4}_", "", names(dfspl[[i]]))
}
do.call(rbind, dfspl)

#            Experiment   Site Year 1_mean_temp 1_precip 2_mean_temp 2_precip
# 2013.195 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 2013.223 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 2013.245 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 2013.271 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
# 2014.196 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014  -14.078710    21.97  -13.500357    28.95
# 2014.224 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014  -14.078710    21.97  -13.500357    28.95
```

Comment: If you want to convert back to standard `data.frame` end by doing `setDF(df2)`

Comment: When running .SD, I get the error ``Error in `[.data.table`(df, , .SD[, .SD, .SDcols = names(.SD) %flike%  :  Column 44 of result for group 2 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.`` This is a problem because I in fact have dozens of columns to retain and there is no way to make them all the same class. I proceeded despite the error and got a data set that was 2000 rows shorter than expected.

Comment: The base R solution works great, and like the other solutions that work it is missing two rows compared to the original data set.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish your goal without any pivoting or explicit loops, by matching column names against the value of `Year` in each row, using `rowwise` and `map`.

This creates a list column, which you can `unnest` to produce the correct values for each year's data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

cols <- colnames(df)
df <- tibble(df)

df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.character(Year)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    tmp_df = list(
      df %>% select(one_of(cols[map_lgl(cols, ~str_detect(., c_across(Year)))])) %>% 
        rename_with(~str_replace(., "_\\d{4}", "")) %>%
        slice(1)
      )
    ) %>%
  select(Experiment, Site, Year, tmp_df) %>%
  unnest_wider(tmp_df)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Experiment   Site   Year  `1_mean_temp` `1_precip` `2_mean_temp` `2_precip`
  <chr>        <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>
1 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013          -8.59       14.2         -7.22       27.9
2 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013          -8.59       14.2         -7.22       27.9
3 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013          -8.59       14.2         -7.22       27.9
4 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013          -8.59       14.2         -7.22       27.9
5 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014         -14.1        22.0        -13.5        29.0
6 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014         -14.1        22.0        -13.5        29.0
```

Comment: I like the approach. On the larger data set, this code takes a really long time to run- I'm not sure it would finish running if I gave it the chance. I made a new data set with just the climate columns and Experiment, Site, and Year and retaining only a handful of climate columns and it still didn't run in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a round-trip pivot from long to wide and back again and filtering the data inbetween:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Experiment, Site, Year, rowid), names_pattern = "(\\d+)_(\\d{4})_(.*)", names_to = c("obs", "yr", "meas")) %>%
  filter(Year == yr) %>%
  select(-yr) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(obs, meas), values_from = value, names_prefix = "X")

# A tibble: 6 x 8
  rowid Experiment   Site    Year X1_mean_temp X1_precip X2_mean_temp X2_precip
  <int> <chr>        <chr>  <int>        <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 IREE- N Rate Waseca  2013        -8.59      14.2        -7.22      27.9
2     2 IREE- N Rate Waseca  2013        -8.59      14.2        -7.22      27.9
3     3 IREE- N Rate Waseca  2013        -8.59      14.2        -7.22      27.9
4     4 IREE- N Rate Waseca  2013        -8.59      14.2        -7.22      27.9
5     5 IREE- N Rate Waseca  2014       -14.1       22.0       -13.5       29.0
6     6 IREE- N Rate Waseca  2014       -14.1       22.0       -13.5       29.0
```

Comment: This works great. Like the answer from Kevin A, for some reason the output has two fewer rows than the input. It's likely a problem with the data set, but the Python code didn't have that problem. I haven't been able to diagnose it.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** This should work pretty generally, *[edit: but not if column types differ]*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

df_left <- df %>% select(Experiment:Year)
df_right <- df %>% select(-Experiment:-Year)

df_right_new <- 
  df_right %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("Month", "Year", "Property"), extra = 'merge') %>%
  unite("Month_Property", c(Month, Property) ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Month_Property, values_from = value, values_fn = unique) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.integer(Year))

df_new <- left_join(df_left, df_right_new)
```

Output of `df_new`

```
    Experiment   Site Year 1_mean_temp 1_precip 2_mean_temp 2_precip
1 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
2 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
3 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
4 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2013   -8.586774    14.17   -7.224286    27.94
5 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014  -14.078710    21.97  -13.500357    28.95
6 IREE- N Rate Waseca 2014  -14.078710    21.97  -13.500357    28.95
```

---

**Method 2 (improved):** Works across mixed data types, *faster* than first solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df_left <- df %>% select(Experiment:Year)
df_right <- df %>% select(-Experiment:-Year) %>% distinct()
year_name <- names(df_right) %>%
  strsplit(fixed = TRUE, split = "_") %>%
  sapply(function(i) c(i[2], paste(i[-2], collapse = "_")))

df_new <- lapply(seq(unique(year_name[2,])), function(i) {
  name_match <- which(year_name[2,] == unique(year_name[2, i]))
  tibble(
    Year = as.integer(year_name[1, name_match]),
    Value = unlist(df_right[name_match])
  ) %>% rename(!!unique(year_name[2,])[[i]] := Value)
}) %>% 
  append(list(as_tibble(df_left)), 0) %>%
  purrr::reduce(left_join, by = "Year")
```

Comment: This is a solid approach, but it doesn't work with the larger data set because I have dozens more non-climate columns that I need to retain (such as latitude, grain yield, plot number).  I get the following error: ``Error: Can't combine `LAT` <double> and `Key` <character>``

Comment: Good call @ginger_cat, I added a 2nd method which handles mixed data types. The error for my first method on your bigger dataset is due to trying to force doubles and characters into the same column. The new method handles this more carefully and is 10% faster.